# How to determine the necessary imgur API endpoint given only the image id?

Tags: imgur

If I have an imgur url, say https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIYzK.jpg (cat picture), how can I determine what API endpoint I need to use?

For instance, if I do a normal /image endpoint on that image I get `'title'` as `None`, but if I do a /gallery/image endpoint I get `'title'` as `u'He totally forgot about his tongue for five minutes'`

So in my situation I always want the endpoint that's going to give me a title.  How can I achieve this?  Is there a way of decoding the image id?  I know I could always try several different endpoints until `'title'` is not `None` but that's rather expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Always do the gallery/{objectid} which will return either an image or album. As I understand the image differs slightly from a gallery image in that the user can choose a certain gallery title without applying that title to the image in their account.